# Huawei Game Service problem, the real-name authentication page cannot be invoked

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

When a user uses an account to log in to the game and choose Settings > Huawei ID on the mobile phone, the system displays a message indicating that the account has not been authenticated.

The game is played successfully. The page for real-name authentication is not displayed, and the game can be played properly.

Report the game event and game interruption event according to the document and perform the anti-obsession verification.

An exception occurs when the gamebegin event is reported. The error code is 7022. The error code indicates that the user is an adult user or a user who has not performed real-name authentication.

Invoke the playersClient.getPlayerExtraInfo interface to obtain user information. If the user is not an adult and the obtained game duration is -1, the real-name authentication is not performed.

The real-name authentication page should be forcibly displayed when a user without real-name authentication logs in to the system. However, the real-name authentication page is not displayed. In addition, the playerClient.getPlayerExtraInfo interface is used to obtain user information, indicating that the user is not an adult and the obtained game duration is -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, real-name authentication is mandatory for online games. This is normal because Huawei operations personnel perform real-name authentication on all online games in batches.